# amble to a halt, amble to stop

Tags: infinitives

> The brothers marched to the end of the lane, **ambling to a halt** on the corner where they met the wider road. Andrew reached into the hedge, groped around for a while, then drew out a half-full packet of Benson & Hedges and a slightly damp box of matches. After several false starts, the heads of the matches crumbling against the strike, he succeeded in lighting up. Two or three deep drags, and then the grumbling engine of the school bus broke the stillness. Andrew carefully knocked out the glowing head of his cigarette and stowed the rest back in the packet. 
>   (The Casual Vacancy, by J. K. Rowling)

The phrase, *to a halt*, seems to be an adjunct or complement denoting that after having ambled they stopped. Here I got wondering if it were a to-infinitve, e.g. ‘*ambling to stop*,’ can this deliver the same meaning? I like to know, though in numerous cases to-infinitives denote purpose meaning, e.g. *I went into ELL to ask a question*, whether it could denote resultative meaning. In ‘*he ambled to stop*,’ there wouldn’t be any possibility that he ambled for the purpose of stop at least in the context.

Comment: *ambling to a halt* <== "to a halt" looks like a PP (not an infinitival clause), and the "a halt" looks like a NP due to the determinative "a" which is usually realizing the determiner function in a NP. (Though, there can be exceptions, such as the non-standard *"The thief went **a** running that a-way, officer"*.)

Comment: @F.E. Yes, so I said, the phrase, not infinitive. And I used the term for 'amble [to stop].'

Comment: To "come to a halt" is idiomatic.  "Ambled to a halt" makes poor sense.

Comment: @TRomano How does *ambled to a halt* make poor sense? It seems as idiomatic, if not as common, as *ambled to a stop.*

Comment: @CarSmack: When we say "he came to a halt" there is the sense of *eventual completion*, but completion nonetheless. Motion has ceased. But "ambled" suggests *ongoing* locomotion. "Ambled to a stop" is like saying  "He walked to a stop".   One who is marching quick-step can "slow (down) to a walk". One can "walk to" a place. But one cannot "walk to a stop" (excluding, of course, a "bus stop").

Comment: @TRomano I *agree* with you that *amble to stop* is problematic. Because *amble* suggests ongoing locomotion. But even a quick search of Google Books shows that *amble to **a** stop* is idiomatic. Itsm that *amble to a stop* means to amble to a place, and that place **is** indeed *a stop,* whether a bus stop or a stop anywhere.

Comment: I disagree. *Amble to a (bus) stop* is not an equivalent for "come to a halt".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your alternative construction is possible.  In that case, I would change it to

> … ambling to stop **at** the corner…

However, I think that it doesn't work well with the primary clause of the sentence:

> The brothers **marched** to the end of the lane, …

The idea being conveyed is that they walked purposefully, then gradually relaxed and slowed down, until the stop.  Having three verbs, *marched*, *ambling*, and *stop*, is excessive and confuses the picture, in my opinion.  Leaving *stop* or *halt* as a noun is stylistically better.

---

Incidentally, *grinding to a halt* is a more frequently used expression (describing a lot of friction involved in the deceleration).

Comment: Can you provide examples of *amble(d)(-ing) to stop*, please.

Comment: @CarSmack _"He ambled to stop at the coffee shop, then rushed home when he realized that he had left the stove on."_

Comment: @200_success: But "ambled (along the street) to stop (at a place)" is different from "ambled to a stop|halt".

Comment: @TRomano Agreed, the meaning of _ambled to stop somewhere_ is not the same as _ambled to a stop_. My answer advised against such usage. Nevertheless, it demonstrates that the construction is possible.

Comment: I don't think it demonstrates that such a construction is possible, because "ambled, to stop somewhere" and "ambled to a stop" are different animals. In the first, "to" is part of the infinitive "to stop", whereas in "ambled to a halt", "to" is prepositional.

Comment: *He ambled to stop at the coffee shop.* To me, this means *he ambled to stop in at the coffee shop.* That is fine. But I'm unconvinced that *He ambled to stop at the corner* is idiomatic. The same goes for *He ran to stop at the corner.* I'm looking for idiomatic uses of these from any contemporary native English source.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an infinitive, it's a prepositional phrase.

They could have said, "ambling to the end of the lane/corner/door/house/other location."  Here "a halt" indicates a temporal location, the point in time at which their ambling ended.

"Ambling to stop" doesn't really make sense with the verb *amble* but it could work with another movement verb.  Something like

> The student sprinted down the hall, turned the corner, and upon seeing his teacher, **skidded to a stop**.

and

> The student sprinted down the hall, turned the corner, and upon seeing his teacher, **skidded to stop**.

are both grammatically correct, but have different meanings.  The first means that he skidded (slid his feet across the floor) until he stopped.  The second means that he skidded rather than continued running for the purpose of stopping quickly.

Comment: *Skid* works because it includes within it the idea of (eventually) slowing down and stopping. Something that skids will stop on a surface that has friction. In other words, skidding involves the stoppage of locomotive power. When something *ambles* there is no such inherent stoppage of locomotive power.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using "stop" in my answer, but the same applies with "halt."

People, vehicles, and animals (and by extension, things such as conversations) do not amble *in order to stop*. They amble because they wish to move slowly, or because they can go no faster.

So "amble to stop" would be unusual. Just as unusual as:

walk to stop
stroll to stop
saunter to stop
march to stop
creep to stop

If you *want* to stop, you **slow down to stop.**

Amble does not mean to *slow down*, it means to *go slowly.*

So, no I don't think *amble to halt* is any more probable than *walk to halt.*

Now, one can certainly change speeds to stop. And one can *start to amble* in order to *finally stop*. But here the meaning, again, is to slow down from a faster pace to stop.

As an aside, one can *come to stop.* But this is a special instance that means *stop*.

(Edit: *skid to stop* works because by definition *skid* means no further locomotive power is applied, and **slowing down to stop** is inevitable.)